# Running Rapidminer with R extension from Java

Tags: java, r, rapidminer

I need a java code that can run rapidminer with R extension. I have read the example of running rapidminer from java from this page (http://rapid-i.com/wiki/index.php?title=Integrating_RapidMiner_into_your_application) But there is no example of running extensions through java. Does anyone know of a way to run Rapidminer with R extensions from java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, turns out you can just dump the rapidminer operation to an .rmp file (similiar to xml) and let the java code run rapidminer to open the .rmp to run the whole operation (R extensions operations included), here's the source http://how2-code.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-read-rmp-file-in-rapidminer-java.html

I hope this can be useful.